# TypeScript: check that the required properties of an argument are defined before passing it to a function call

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

This doesn't compile ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20myFunction(params%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20Date%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3F%3A%20Date%0D%0A%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(params.b)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20myFunctionInternal(params)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20myFunctionInternal(params%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20Date%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20Date%0D%0A%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D)):

```
function myFunction(params: {
    a: Date,
    b?: Date
}) {
    if (params.b) {
        myFunctionInternal(params); // ERROR!
    }
}

function myFunctionInternal(params: {
    a: Date,
    b: Date
}) {}
```

Is there a more elegant workaround than `params as any`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the type guard impacts just the type of the field (`params.b` will have the `undefined` removed) not the type of whole object (`param` will continue to have the type `{ a: Date, b?: Date }`)

Not sure I would call it more elegant, but we can create a type guard that removes the undefined from a type field:

```
type RemoveOptionalFromField<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> & { [P in K]-?: T[P] }

function notNull<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T | RemoveOptionalFromField<T, K>, key: K) : o is RemoveOptionalFromField<T, K> {
    return !!o[key];
}

function myFunction(params: {
    a: Date,
    b?: Date
}) {
    if (notNull(params, 'b')) {
        params.b.getDate()
        myFunctionInternal(params);
    }
}
```

We could even create a version that takes any number of keys:

```
function allNotNull<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T | RemoveOptionalFromField<T, K>, ...keys: K[]) : o is RemoveOptionalFromField<T, K> {
    return keys.every(k => !!o[k]);
}
function myFunction(params: {
    a?: Date,
    b?: Date
}) {
    if (allNotNull(params, 'b', 'a')) {
        params.b.getDate()
        myFunctionInternal(params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I guess you can't use `Date` as a discriminant in a discriminated union, so a user-defined type guard is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

the error message said property 'b' is optional in type '{ a: Date; b?: Date; }' but required in type '{ a: Date; b: Date; }'

It can be solve like this

```
myFunctionInternal(params as {a,b});
```

or

```
myFunctionInternal({a:params.a ,b:params.b});
```

Comment: A good solution but does require some extra typing and an extra object :)

Comment: My real code is more complex than the example, of course, so it would need even more typing.